# angularjs remove array specific element dosen't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

if I push two elements into another `array` and then try to remove the first one ( click at the first button ) the second element is being removed. why ?!?

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/AEhVdOKdDY9cLLPDUi5z?p=preview)

```
$scope.removeFromList = function(p) {
  $scope.found = $.grep($scope.data2, function(e) {
    return e.ID == p.ID;
  });

  var index = $scope.data2.indexOf($scope.found);
  $scope.data2.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Comment: I am not clicking a random bit.ly link. Please post the code here.

Comment: indexOf works for array not for Object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

indexOf works for array not for Object. It returns -1, and so always take the last element.

Try this:

```
    $scope.removeFromList = function (p) {

        var index = $scope.data2.map(function(e) { return e.ID;}).indexOf(p.ID);

         if(index >= 0)
                $scope.data2.splice(index, 1);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happend because indexof is not used to find the objects and return -1 index always which in turn remove the first element always you need to create your own indexof

```
var index = myIndexOf($scope.data2,$scope.found);


function myIndexOf(arr,o) {    
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i].x == o.x && arr[i].y == o.y) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/90WDRBMyu3jxtIfWFoZG?p=preview)